# Safari cannot rotate more than 360 deg

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-transitions, css-transforms

Can Safari 6.0.2 perform a rotation of more than 360 degrees? I have a [simple experiment](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/h7paauob). Try it in Chrome release(not canary, will break, moz also will break) and Safari.

UPDATE:Since I found the solution, I have edited make it work properly in Chrome and Safari, but I still providing a improper version and proper version for compare.(note: Safari version is 6.0.2 at this time). BTW, I test in MAC only, not yet test in Windows

Improper version :  [Fail in Safari](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/3rahxwfj)

Proper version : [Simple Experiment](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/h7paauob)

Comment: Just on a sidenote - seems to work in canary over here.

Comment: really? my canary , all linear-gradient and radial gradient break, my canary is a clean version , without extension change in flags

Comment: http://s8.postimage.org/td5i9u8wl/chun_2.png , this is the screenshot it suppose to be, sure it is already rotateZ(900deg) or 180deg

Comment: Oh my bad, in canary it doesn't display properly indeed. I thought you meant the rotation or so, which does work, no? The initial 'image' isn't proper either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple transform style at the same time when transitting , example

.chun {

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.0); /*we want rotate, so remove this*/
transform: scale(1.0); /*we want rotate, so remove this*/

-webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
transition: all .8s ease;
```

}

.chun:hover {

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-900deg); /*we want this to be rotate few cycle*/
transform: rotate(-900deg);
```

}

cannot have scale on normal state and rotate for hovering state.

This definetely is a bug(or something else) in safari, because Chrome can handle it properly.